# Здравствуйте, возникла идея эмуляции нескольких мониторов

Tags: windows, winapi, драйвер, hdmi, monitor

возникла идея эмуляции нескольких мониторов, захвата их изображения и передачи в вр приложение, подскажите через какой драйвер или api можно это сделать, в доках nvidia ничего не нашел(

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Монитор - это устройство внешнее, соответственно его эмулировать нельзя. Можно эмулировать графический адаптер. Для этого придется писать драйвер WDDM.